# Vector iterators incompatible error for a vector holding iterators of another vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, incompatibletypeerror

With reference to this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204856/in-c-debug-assertion-failed-window-pops-up-i-get-vector-iterators-incompati/45205112#45205112) , I corrected my mistake & changed the iterators to be of same "vector type" i.e.

I replaced the line

> auto startIter = table.begin();

with

> auto startIter =  tabTypeIterVector[0];

in the for loop in     AccessTableIteratorsVector() function.
wrt below code, however, **I'm still getting the "Debug assertion failed, vector iterators incompatible error,** 
when this line is hit in for loop

> itloop !=-endIter

```
typedef vector<vector<string> tableDataType;
vector<tableDataType::Iterator> tabTypeIterVector;
tableDataType table;
FillRows(vector<string> vstr)
{
    table.push_back(vstr);
    if(some_condition_satisfied_for_this_row())
    {
        tableDataType::Iterator rowIT = table.end();
        tabTypeIterVector.push_back(rowIT);
    }
}


In another function:

AccessTableIteratorsVector()
{
auto startIter =  tabTypeIterVector[0];
auto endIter = tabTypeIterVector[1];
   for(auto itloop=startIter; itloop !=-endIter;itloop++)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to store a vector of iterators? What is the *actual* problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: …and why aren't you simply storing indices, which don't get invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) might cause a reallocation of the data contained in the vector. And that reallocation will make all iterators to the vector *invalid*. Dereferencing invalid iterators leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Indexes into the vector will continue to stay valid, unless you remove elements from the vector.

Comment: Is it possible to get the index from the a valid vector iterator ?

Comment: I would be more concerned that the `end()` vector is the one getting stored.